# Flexslider as carousel hide/show navigation

Tags: navigation, hide, flexslider

I'm using a flexslider for my carousel. Let's say I have a box with width of 800px, and my carusel items are 200px width. It all works ok if I input more than 4 carousel items. But if for example I put only 2 I still get the navigation arrows that are not needed in that case.

Can they be set to appaer only if the number of slides goes over the entire width. Let me just point out that the width is dynamic regarding the browser resolution(responsive).

THANKS in advance!